# Google Sheets I need the column sums() of a table produced by a query()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-custom-function

I have a query() that outputs a table with two columns (A and B) of numbers. Pictured in IMAGE #1.

```
=QUERY(myData!A:G, "Select E,F WHERE D ='Books'")
```

**IMAGE #1**

[image]

But I need a function that outputs only three values. Pictured in the green row of IMAGE #2. The number of rows is variable.

1. Sum of column A
2. Sum of column B
3. Sum of column C (column C is the product of A*B)

Thanks for any help you can provide!

**IMAGE #2**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
={
QUERY(myData!A:G,"SELECT SUM(E), SUM(F) WHERE D = 'Books'"),
{"product";SUM(QUERY(myData!A:G,"SELECT E*F WHERE D = 'Books'"))}
}
```

This is simply uses [aggregation functions](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#aggregation-functions).

Comment: Thank you for your help. The `=QUERY(myData!A:G, "Select SUM(E), SUM(F) WHERE D ='Books'")` portion of the function works but the `SUM(E*F)` portion throws this error. `Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "*" "* "" at line 1, column 14. Was expecting: ")" ...` Do you know how to correct that? Thanks again!

Comment: it seems that aggregation functions don't work on modified columns. Nevertheless, here is a fixed formula. It queries for data, then just use the native `SUM` function to add it all up instead of using the `QUERY`'s sum function. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: That worked but the 1st instance of  `WHERER` has a typo. Thank you David!

Comment: Thank you Mr. B for correcting my typo! If you would, please do accept my answer by hitting the checkmark below to show that this in fact did help you. (and give me a bit more reputation.) Much appreciated!